# Xpath contains text() doesnt work with comments

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

Can someone please explain why i cant find h2 which contains text?
Piece of html i am looking for

```
<h2 class="heading">
    <!---->
    "Some text"
    <!---->
</h2>
```

Tried to use already

```
//*[contains(text(),'Some text')]
```

But it does not find it.

Edit:
Looks like issue is due to shadow-root element.
Using your methods still did not help me to find the element. But now atleast i know i can use your methods in different places

Comment: It's simple. Html comment is not element's text.

Comment: Can you please print or log out the value of the `text()` method? Then we can see why your method does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem illustrates a general rule: you very rarely need to use the `text()` expression. Nearly all the time, using `string()` to get the string value of an element is better; and most of the time you don't even need to call `string()`, because when a string is needed, you can supply a node and its string value will automatically be extracted.

So you can write

```
//*[contains(string(),'Some text')]
```

or more simply

```
//*[contains(.,'Some text')]
```

The string value of an element (obtained using the `string()` function) is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes.

This does have the drawback that if an `h2` element contains "Some text", then all the ancestors of the `h2` element also contain "Some text". So you may want to be more selective about which elements you search for.

Comment: Remove * else it will find all parents

Answer (score 1):

That's because your XPath means that *first text node contains `'Some text'`* while it doesn't. Note that `h2` has several text nodes:

```
<h2 class="heading"> "First text node"
    <!---->
    "Second text node"
    <!---->"Third text node"
</h2>
```

You can either check *second text node* explicitly:

```
//h2[contains(text()[2],'Some text')]
```

or check that `h2` *text representation* contains required text:

```
//h2[contains(.,'Some text')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//h2[text()[contains(.,"Some")]]
```

## use above locator . the text() returns and array now check if the returned array ( which is called using . ) contains the text

Just open the devtool console and print

```
 $x("//h2/text()")
```

you can see an array of 3 text nodes is printed.

Comment: This might work in this particular example, but it will still fail if the comment occurs in the middle of the text you are searching for.